# How to include a XML snippet into a XML document

Tags: xml, powershell, doctype

I am using XML files as configuration files for my PowerShell scripts based on the blog post found at [rkeithhill.wordpress.com](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2006/06/01/creating-and-using-a-configuration-file-for-your-powershell-scripts). Some of my scripts shares the same settings and I would like to include those settings from an external XML file. What I have done is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY shareddata SYSTEM "shared.xml">
]>
<configuration >
  <appSettings >
    &shareddata;
    <add key="motorcycle" value="Husqvarna TE610" />
    <add key="car" value="Ford Mondeo" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and the `shared.xml` file contains (one line only):

```xml
<add key="backhoe" value="Volvo BM 430 Hymas" />
```

Using the following code snippet I load the XML and print it to the console:

```psh
$config = [xml](get-content $path)
$text = $config.OuterXml
Write-Verbose "[LoadConfig] $text"
```

The output is:

```xml
VERBOSE: [LoadConfig] <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc[
<!ENTITY shareddata SYSTEM "shared.xml">
]>
<configuration><appSettings>&shareddata;
<add key="motorcycle"    value="Husqvarna TE610" />
<add key="car" value="Ford Mondeo" /></appSettings> </configuration>
```

The way I load the XML does not include the content of `shared.xml`, but it does parse the `DOCTYPE` tag, since if I revert to an invalid file it will fail.

---

So, how could I get PowerShell to fully include the XML snippet, so that `loadconfig` will find the key and value for my backhoe as well?

---

I have also tried

```psh
$Document = ( Select-Xml -Path myfile.xml -XPath / ).Node
```

but it won't load anything as long as I have the `&shareddata;` in the config file:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your example in C# and it doesn't work either. This works in C# however once you change `shared.xml` to contain `TEST VALUE` value (i.e. only simple values are allowed, not xml) but it still doesn't work in PS:

```
<configuration >
  <appSettings >
    <test>&shareddata;</test>
    <add key="motorcycle" value="Husqvarna TE610" />
    <add key="car" value="Ford Mondeo" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Using this code:

```
$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load("D:\config.xml")
$doc.configuration.appSettings.add

key        value
---        -----
motorcycle Husqvarna TE610
car        Ford Mondeo
```

The same examaple in C# works:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("d:\\config.xml");
var x = doc["configuration"]["appSettings"]["test"];
Console.WriteLine(x.InnerText);
```

It outputs

```
TEST VALUE
```

It seems that Powershell sets `doc.XmlResolver = null;` option to prevent security related issues which you can see in PS as `$doc.XmlResolver` returning nothing. I didn't event succeed to manually set the resolver via `$doc.XmlResolver = new-object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver`.

**NOW**,

you could use variable substitution to achieve the effect:

```
<configuration >
  <appSettings >
    $shared_xml
    <add key="motorcycle" value="Husqvarna TE610" />
    <add key="car" value="Ford Mondeo" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

$shared_xml = Get-Content 'D:\shared.xml'
[xml]$config = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString((gc $path))
```

You could make this easier if you enumerate variables in config block and load appropriate files. You would be able then to not know in advance what files are included.

**NOW**,

this all seems like a lot of trouble unless there is some normal solution to the resolver problem. But the idea of keeping the config in XML is wrong on so many levels to be honest. Why use XML when you can use powershell config:

```
$config = @{ }
$config.motorcycle = 'Husqvarna TE610'
$config.car = 'Ford Mondeo'

$shared = @{}
$shared.backhoe = "Volvo BM 430 Hymas"

$config + $shared
```

Outputs

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
backhoe                        Volvo BM 430 Hymas
car                            Ford Mondeo
motorcycle                     Husqvarna TE610
```

You can make this follow "include" pattern such as:

**config.ps1**

```
$config = @{ 
   motorcycle = 'Husqvarna TE610'
   car = 'Ford Mondeo'
}
. shared1.ps1
...
. sharedN.ps1
```

**sharedN.ps1**

```
$config.sharedN_cfg1 = 1
$config.sharedN_cfg2 = 2
```

If you really need XML from that point you could use `ConvertTo-CliXML` and friends afterwards.

If you still want to pursue your direction I suggest you look at the [XInclude](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302291.aspx) (you need 3thd party assembly to make this work).

Comment: I did no actual considerations when it comes to pros and cons for using XML-config back in the days. I found a working solution and started using it and now it backfires ... seems that I must look into the usage of Powershell config instead. Just now realizing that I do not need to actually change all my scripts in a big bang, I could just use it for the shared approach, and then over time replace use of XML-config.

Answer (score 1):

Partially informed by data here : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-data-basics-xml/

In Powershell, there are multiple ways to load XML documents and they don't all work the same with external entities.

Assume we have a simple pair of XML documents :

`a.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc[
    <!ENTITY includeSnippet SYSTEM "../path/to/b.xml">
]>
<stuff>
    &includeSnippet;
    <something>foo</something>
</stuff>
```

`b.xml`

```
<somethingElse>bar</somethingElse>
```

In Powershell we might normally do something like `$myVar = [xml](Get-Content a.xml)` and we would expect that things work -

```
$myVar.stuff.somethingElse ?= 'bar'  --> false (was not loaded from b.xml)
$myVar.stuff.something ?= 'foo'  --> true (was in a.xml)
```

But this doesn't work as outlined above - PowerShell's Get Content provider is just reading text from the disk - the [xml] cast (to an XmlNode) interprets that text as XML but it's "too late" to load additional resources. If instead we load the xml this way :

```
$myFile = resolve-path(".\a.xml")
$myDoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$myDoc.load($myFile)
```

The Entity inclusion works - sort of. I may be misunderstanding the intent of Entity includes here but the contents of `b.xml` are not directly substituted into the `a.xml` document, but rather show up in a new wrapped tag :

```
$myVar.stuff.includeSnippet.somethingElse == 'bar'
$myVar.stuff.something == 'foo'
```

I looked at using XInclude as well (given that Microsoft advocates for it, seems reasonable to think PS would support it?) - basically swapping the `!Entity` piece out for the reference : `<xi:include href="b.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude"/>`

But in this case, NEITHER of the above Powershell XML reading techniques resolve the inclusion file and we get nothing.